# ASP.NET MVC - prevent submit of invalid form using jQuery unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have an ASP.NET project that automatically wires up client side validation using [jQuery.Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) and the [unobtrusive wrapper](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) built by ASP.NET.

a) I definitely have the appropriate libraries: [jquery.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/1.12.4), [jquery.validate.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validate/1.9.0), & [jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-validation-unobtrusive)

b) And the MVC rendering engine is definitely turned on (`ClientValidationEnabled` & `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` in the `appSettings` section of the web.config)

Here's a trivial example where things are broken:

**Model**:

```cs
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```cs
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    Person p = new Person();
    return View(p);
}
```

**View**:

```cs
@model validation.Models.Person

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

This generates the following client side markup:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    
<form action="/Person" method="post">
  <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>
  </div>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When run it will perform the client side validation, noting that some form elements are invalid, but then *also* post back to the server.

Why is it not preventing postback on a form with an invalid state?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Problem

It turns out this happens when you don't include a `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` placeholder for a given form element.

Here's a deeper dive into where the problem occurs:

When a form submits, `jquery.validate.js` will call the following methods:

```js
validate: function( options ) {
  form: function() {
    showErrors: function(errors) {
      defaultShowErrors: function() {
        showLabel: function(element, message) {
          this.settings.errorPlacement(label, $(element) )
```

Where `errorPlacement` will call this method in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`:

```js
function onError(error, inputElement) { 
   var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
       replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")) !== false;
```

When we don't add a placeholder for the validation message, `$(this).find(...)` won't find anything.

Meaning `container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")` will return `undefined`

This poses a problem is when we try to call `$.parseJSON` on an undefined value.  If an error is thrown (and not caught), JavaScript will stop dead in its tracks and never reach the final line of code in the original method (`return false`) which prevents the form from submitting.

### The Solution

#### Upgrade jQuery Validate Unobtrusive

[Newer versions of jQuery Validate](https://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn) handle this better and check for nulls before passing them to `$.parseJSON`

```js
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element
    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
        replaceAttrValue = container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"),
        replace = replaceAttrValue ? $.parseJSON(replaceAttrValue) !== false : null;
```

#### Add ValidationMessageFor

To address the core problem, for every input on your form, make sure to include:

```cs
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

Which will render the following client side markup

```html
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    
<form action="/Person" method="post">
  <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul><li style="display:none"></li></ul>
  </div>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```